# Making an app autolaunch in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am using the note-taking app Joplin on Ubuntu 20.04.3 and would like it to autolaunch and minimize upon login.  Joplin already contains this feature but it warns that it doesn't work in all desktop environments - and it surely doesn't in Gnome 3.36.8.
Is there a way to have the OS autolaunch the app upon login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you will need to use Gnome Tweaks for that version of Gnome. See https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-apps-auto-start.html.en.

Comment: I already had Gnome Tweaks installed and added a Gnome app called Startup Applications that allowed me to add Joplin to the list of startup apps.  Thank you for the guidance!